# Django on_delete SET_NULL not working

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I have models set up like so:

```
class User
  email = models.EmailField(unique=True)

class Store
  owner = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

My expectation is that the `on_delete=models.SET_NULL` means that if a `User` is deleted, the `Store` will not be deleted. However, this suspicion is not confirmed by my tests (see below). Can someone help explain my misunderstanding? And yes, I did run migrations before doing my tests!

This first test tests whether the deletion of a `Store` leads to the deletion of a `User`, which should not be the case. This test passes as expected.

```
def test_delete_store(self):
    self.store.delete()
    with self.assertRaises(Store.DoesNotExist):
        Store.objects.get(pk=self.store.pk)
    self.assertEqual(User.objects.get(pk=self.user.pk), self.user)
```

The following test tests whether the deletion of a user leads to the deletion of the store. The second assert in this test FAILS.

```
def test_delete_user_deletes_store(self):
    self.user.delete()
    with self.assertRaises(User.DoesNotExist):
        User.objects.get(pk=self.user.pk)
    # Check that store is not deleted (this unexpectedly raises a DoesNotExist error)
    self.assertEqual(Store.objects.get(pk=self.store.pk), self.store)
```

Comment: But here you delete the store, not the user?

Comment: In the first test, I delete the store, and things happen as expected.  But in the second test, I deleted the user. But for some reason, it deletes the store!!

Comment: Are you running the two tests in the same testcase? How do you set up data here? Since if the first testcase already deletes the store, then the second testcase, will never have such `Store` anymore.

Comment: What if you set up the data at the beginning of the test case?

Comment: Yes, thank you for the suggestion. I think this is what is going on. I will investigate and then post the answer.

Comment: Assuming you have created the test data in the correct spot, these two tests should be isolated from each other and the test data should be reset in between both tests. Try running the tests individually (`test [path_to_testcase].test_delete_X`) and in reverse (`test --reverse`).

Comment: I am having a similar problem. I create a <handle> object by doing `Handle.create(owner=user)` where <user> is `User.create(username="test", ...)` from django.contrib.auth.models. When I delete the user in my test case `user.delete()` the reference `handle.owner` is not being set to null, as defined in the FK field for the Handle class.